# Responsive font size relative to container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the font size be responsive and auto adjust the font size depends on width & height of the container(image).
But problem now is when I make the screen size smaller, It keep run the font size "1em" only. It start from // font size in the script, Thank you! :)

can I know where is the problem?

```js
$(function() {
// document
 'use strict';

 var t1 = $('div.cp');

 // Settings
 t1.each(function() {
  var _t1 = $(this);
    
  // Different Data type
  if (_t1.data('type') == "c1") 
  {
   _t1.addClass('red').css(
    {
     "background-image" : "url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/violet-vector-leaves-circles-backgrounds-for-powerpoint_PdfkI4q.jpg')",
     "background-size" : "100% 100%"
     }
    );
   _t1.append(
    '<div class="title">' + 'im red' + '</div>'
    );
   $(_t1.children()).wrapAll("<div class='ty-container'/>");
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 });

 // alignment to middle
 $('.cp').on('resize',function() {
  $(".ty-container").css('margin-top', function() {
   return($('.cp').height() - $(this).height()) / 2
  });
 }).resize();

 // font size
 textfit();
 $(window).on('resize', textfit);

 function textfit() {
  var w1 = $('.cp').width()-10;
     var w2 = $('.title').width();
     var wRatio = Math.round(w1 / w2 * 10) / 10;

     var h1 = $('.cp').height()-10;
     var h2 = $('.title').height();
     var hRatio = Math.round(h1 / h2 * 10) / 10;

     var final = Math.min(wRatio, hRatio);

  $('.cp').css('font-size', final + 'em');
 }
});//end
```

```css
.cp{width:340px;height:156px;display:table;text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="cp" data-type="c1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use font size vw that means viewport width. Must declare viewport width meta at header. and use font-size in css.  example font-size: 50vw;

Comment: font-size: 50vw; seems a bit exessive. Two letters will fill the screen.